# Fiddler - Capture HTTPS Traffic from Web Application

Tags: ssl, encryption, fiddler

I've been banging my head against a wall for a little while now trying to get Fiddler to decrypt communications for one of the web apps I support.

***Versions***

Fiddler: 4.6.2.3

OS: Windows 2012 R2

.NET: 4.6

***Settings***

Decrypt HTTPS Traffic: Enabled (...from all processes)

Fiddler Root Certificate: Installed (A few times now...)

```
Protocols: <client>;ssl3;tls1.0;tls1.1;tls1.2
```

In the web.config I've added:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true">
  <proxy proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" bypassonlocal="False"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

The error I'm getting in the Fiddler Log is:

```
The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm for pipe
```

I scanned the first endpoint that threw the error, however keep in mind that fiddler cannot establish a handshake with any https endpoint:

```
TLS 1      offered
TLS 1.1    offered
TLS 1.2    offered
```

I tried adding this to the FiddlerScript after some research:

```
if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT") && oSession.HostnameIs("dev-wsv-OMITTED.OMITTED.ad"))
    { 
        oSession["x-OverrideSslProtocols"] = "tls1.0";
    }
```

No success. I'm at a loss. Why can the server establish a handshake and Fiddler cannot? All the non encrypted traffic is captured without issue, but I just can't seem to get HTTPS decryption to play nice.

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are not a fresh Fiddler user the SSL config may be outdated. On the HTTPS config page execute Actions -> Reset all Certificates.

Comment: Tried that a few times now, no change unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before. It seems that you have not created a keystore with the Fiddler Root Certificate.

Step 1: Export the certificate
[image]

Step 2: Create a keystore with this certificate

```
keytool.exe -import -file C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\FiddlerRoot.cer -keystore FiddlerKeystore -alias Fiddler
```

Step 3: Add the following VM options

[image]

That should be it.

You can refer to [this msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2017/04/26/capture-java-vm-traffic-using-fiddler/) for more details.